# Definition of multiplicity of value of a complex function

Tags: complex-analysis, functions

This has got to be a trivial question, but I wanna make sure that I get it right.

I'm reading some literature on theorems about complex functions sharing values, such as the paper by L. A. Rubel and C. C. Yang, *Values shared by an entire function and its derivatives* (in: Proceedings of
Conference Univ. of Kentucky, Lexinton Ky (1976), Lecture Notes in Math., Vol. 599. Berlin, Springer, 101–103 (1977)). It starts with the definition

> We say that two meromorphic functions $f$ and $g$ share the value $a$ ($a=\infty$ is allowed) if $f(z)=a$ whenever $g(z)=a$ and also $g(z)=a$ whenever $f(z)=a$, counting multiplicities in both cases.

When we are not talking about the zeroes of a function, what is the definition of multiplicity of a value? That is, if for a complex function $f$, $f(z_0)=a$, what is the definition of multiplicity of $a$ as a value of $f$ at this point $z_0$?

Comment: multiplicity of the zero of $f-a$ at $z_0$

Comment: @Conrad: Thank you!